# How to get a substring from Id?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following `<img>` elements below on different pages. How can I grab all the `data-uuid` attributes from all using javascript?

It should be able to handle if there is only 1 `<img>` element or if there are more than 1.

Page foo:

```js
$('[data-uuid]').on('click', function() {
 alert($(this).attr('data-uuid'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='https://placeimg.com/200/200/animals' data-uuid='123'>
    <img src='https://placeimg.com/200/200/animals?t=1526063181645' data-uuid='456'>
    <img src='https://placeimg.com/200/200/animals?t=1526063190252' data-uuid='789'>
```

Page bar:

```
<img src='some-url-5' data-uuid=157>
```

Comment: *"The javascript should be able"* what javascript? What have you tried?

Comment: Use querySelectorAll then just loop through and make whatever you want

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan updated the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`querySelectorAll`<sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [Attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```js
let uuids = [...document.querySelectorAll("[data-uuid]")].map(el => 
    el.dataset.uuid
);

console.log( uuids )
```

```html
<img src='some-url' data-uuid=123>
<img src='some-url1' data-uuid=456>
<img src='some-url2' data-uuid=789>
```

A jQuery version:

```js
var uuids = $("[data-uuid]").get().map(function(el) {
  return el.getAttribute("data-uuid");
});

console.log( uuids )
```

```html
<img src='some-url' data-uuid=123>
<img src='some-url1' data-uuid=456>
<img src='some-url2' data-uuid=789>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to look for all the img that has a data-uuid attribute

```
  document.querySelectorAll("img[data-uuid]");
```

something like this